# Generate javadoc for test classes of Maven project in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, javadoc

I think that the title is pretty self explanatory, how can I achieve that? By default Maven's javadoc plugin generates documentation only for "normal" classes.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/test-javadocs.html

Comment: @Compass That is not the case for netbeans. Documentation is generated in completely different place and there is no trace of any test package documentation so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem. To generate javadoc of test packages you have to go to properties of Maven project->Actions->Generate Javadoc and there add the goal: javadoc:test-javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

You can set additional source paths for the `maven-javadoc-plugin`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourcepath>${basedir}/src/main/java;${basedir}/src/test/java</sourcepath>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

You may also want to tweak other `javadoc:javadoc` goal settings. You get set the complete list of options at its official [site](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html).